# Drupal 7 - LDAP Password Not Working

Tags: drupal-7, ldap

I'm having an issue where my password from LDAP is not being recognized by Drupal 7. I do have a successful connection to LDAP. And I'm able to import all my users into Drupal.

Cannot figure out why the password isn't working. If I manually set a password on the imported LDAP users, that password does work.

Here is what is in the log:

```
TYPE    ldap_authentication
DATE    Wednesday, March 26, 2014 - 10:19
USER    Anonymous (not verified)
LOCATION    http://drupal_sc.int.server.org/drupal/node?destination=node
REFERRER    http://drupal_sc.int.server.org/drupal/
MESSAGE gormans : Trying server J LDAP where bind_method = 1. Error: Success
SEVERITY    debug
HOSTNAME    10.8.0.174
**************************************************
TYPE    ldap_authentication
DATE    Wednesday, March 26, 2014 - 10:19
USER    Anonymous (not verified)
LOCATION    http://drupal_sc.int.server.org/drupal/node?destination=node
REFERRER    http://drupal_sc.int.server.org/drupal/
MESSAGE smith1 : Authentication result id=0 auth_result=3 (Sorry, unrecognized username or password.)
SEVERITY    debug
HOSTNAME    10.8.0.174
OPERATIONS  
*************************************************

TYPE    ldap_authentication
DATE    Wednesday, March 26, 2014 - 10:19
USER    Anonymous (not verified)
LOCATION    http://drupal_sc.int.server.org/drupal/node?destination=node
REFERRER    http://drupal_sc.int.server.org/drupal/
MESSAGE gormans : Failed ldap authentication. User may have authenticated successfully by other means in a mixed authentication site. LDAP Authentication Error #: 3 error message: Sorry, unrecognized username or password.
SEVERITY    debug
HOSTNAME    10.8.0.174
OPERATIONS
```

Huge thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure this out. Even though the module says, "Anonymous Bind: Use no credentials to bind to LDAP server. This option will not work on most LDAPS connections", I changed it to be anonymous.

What I was originally doing was putting in my own super-user credentials into the binding method.